# Menu and dropdown menu are not verticaly scrollable

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, scroll

When I put the longest side of the mobile phone in landscape position, I cannot scroll to see all the direct links neither I can see all the links off the dropdowns menus.

I tried to put height: 100%; or height: 100vh; and overflow-y: scroll; at many places but nothing worked.

If you want to check : https://www.veganimaliste.com/index.php

```
/* LOGO ##############################################################*/
/* LOGO ##############################################################*/
/* LOGO ##############################################################*/
.logo {
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 27px;
    height: 73px;
    background-color: black;
}
.logo a {
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 28px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 18px 5px 25px 5px;
    letter-spacing: -.5px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 0 lightgreen;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
}
/*   couleur du Veg du logo ----------------------------*/
.logo .logo-color {
    color: lightgreen;
    margin-right: 0;
}
.logo .logo-color-2 {
    color: dimgray;
    margin-right: 0;
}
/* MENUM ################################################################*/
/* MENUM ################################################################*/
/* MENUM ################################################################*/
.menu-lang {
    color: lightgreen;
    font-size: 26px;
    font-style: italic;
}
.menu-wrap.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    /*d'autres proprietes si besoin*/
}
.menu-wrap {
    font-style: normal;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 200;
    height: 73px;
    background-color: black;
}
.topnav {
    position: absolute;
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 32px 0 0;
    height: 73px;
    background: black;
    letter-spacing: -1.5px;
}
/* liens du menu qui n'ont pas de sous menu -----------------------------------------------------*/
.topnav a {
    color: white;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 25px 10px 19px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 21px;
}
/* images icones pour le menu ---------------------*/
.topnav img {
    height: 14px;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 4px 0 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
/* images icones pour le menu qui n'ont pas de texte---------------------*/
img.sans-texte {
    height: 22px;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 4px 0 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
/* images icones dans le texte---------------------*/
img.sans-texte-2 {
    height: 35px;
    width: auto;
    background: black;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 4px 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
img.sans-texte-2:hover {
    transform: translateY(-2px);
}
/*.topnav a, .dropdown button, .dropdown-content a {
      cursor: pointer;
}*/
.topnav .icon {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: lightgreen;
    display: none;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    border: none;
}
/* SOUS MENU #########################################################*/
/* SOUS MENU #########################################################*/
/* SOUS MENU #########################################################*/
/* aligenement à gauche des liens des sous menu ******/
.dropdown {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
/* liens qui ont un sous menu ---------------------------------------------------------------*/
.dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 21px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 28px 2px 20px 5px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    top: 0;
}
/* groupe sous menu --------------------------------*/
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: black;
    width: auto;
    z-index: 1;
}
/* liens des sous menu ------------------------------*/
.dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: lightgreen;
    font-size: 19px;
    padding: 15px 35px 15px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    letter-spacing: normal;
}
/* bordur inférieure des liens des sous menu ---------*/
.dropdown-content a {
    border-top: 1px solid #4B4A4A;
}
/* hover sur les liens qui ont des sous menu ----------*/
.topnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #2C2C2C;
    color: white;
}
/* meme chose */
.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #2C2C2C;
    color: white;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
/* MEDIA QUERY ################################################################*/
/* MEDIA QUERY ################################################################*/
/* MEDIA QUERY ################################################################*/
@media screen and (max-width: 1100px) {
    /* ----- disparitoin du menu horizontal  --- */
    .topnav a, .dropdown .dropbtn {
        display: none;
        background: black;
        z-index: 100;
    }
    /* ---- apparition du bouton ouvrir du menu vertical ----- */
    .topnav a.icon {
        position: absolute;
        float: right;
        display: block;
        top: 0;
        margin: 0;
        right: 0;
        padding: 26px 25px 16px 22px;
        border: none;
    }
    /* ------ hover du bouton fermer du menu vertical ---- */
    .topnav a.icon:hover {
        background: black;
        border: none;
    }
    /* ----------- menu ----------------*/
    /* ----------- menu ----------------*/
    /* ----------- menu ----------------*/
    /*------------ tous les liens (avec ou sans menu) -------*/
    .topnav.responsive {
        position: absolute;
        background-color: black;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 204;
        letter-spacing: normal;
    }
    /* ------------ menu avec sous menu -------------*/
    .topnav.responsive .icon {
        position: absolute;
        float: right;
        display: block;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        width: 72px;
        height: 72px;
    }
    /* ---------- liens sans sous menu ------ */
    .topnav.responsive a {
        width: 100%;
        float: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
        padding-left: 35px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #4B4A4A;
    }
    /* -------- mettre en colonne ------------ */
    .topnav.responsive .dropdown {
        float: none;
    }
    /* ----------- sous menu -------------*/
    /* ----------- sous menu -------------*/
    /* ----------- sous menu -------------*/
    .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding-left: 20px;
    }
    /* ------- afficher liens qui ont des sous-liens ------*/
    .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
        width: 100%;
        padding-left: 35px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #4B4A4A;
        letter-spacing: normal;
    }
}
/* ----------- bouton ouvrir du menu vertical -----------*/
.topnav .menu-open {
    display: block;
}
/* -------- disparition du bouton fermer du menu vertical ------ */
.topnav .menu-close {
    display: none;
}
/* ------- disparition du bouton ouvrir du menu vertical -------*/
.topnav.responsive .menu-open {
    display: none;
}
/* ------- bouton fermer du menu vertical -------- */
.topnav.responsive .menu-close {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    padding: 26px 25px 16px 22px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .logo a {
        font-size: 95%;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 0 lightgreen;
    }
}



<span id="haut-page" class="anchor"></span>
<div class="menu-wrap">
    <div class="logo"><a href="index.php" target="_self"><span class="logo-line"><span class="logo-color">veg</span>animaliste</span>.com</a> </div>
    <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">

        <a href="index.php" title="Page d'accueil" target="_self"><img class="sans-texte" src="img/menu/home-g.png" ></a>

        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn">VÉGANISME <img src="img/menu/down-g.png"/></button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="v-intro.php" target="_self"><img src="img/menu/dot-g.png"/>Vérités ugentes à connaître</a>
                <a href="articles.php" target="_self"><img src="img/menu/dot-g.png"/>Articles</a>
                <a href="reponses.php" target="_self"><img src="img/menu/dot-g.png"/>Réponses aux non-véganes</a>
                <a href="reponses-av.php" target="_self"><img src="img/menu/dot-g.png"/>Réponses de AV aux non-véganes</a>
                <a href="qui-sont-ils.php" target="_self"><img src="img/menu/dot-g.png"/>Qui sont-ils? </a>
                <a href="ce-que-nous-pouvons-faire.php" target="_self"><img src="img/menu/dot-g.png"/>Ce que nous pouvons faire</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn">DOCUMENTS <img src="img/menu/down-g.png"/></button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="videos.php" target="_self"><img src="img/menu/dot-g.png"/>Vidéos</a>
                <a href="defenitions.php" target="_self"><img src="img/menu/dot-g.png"/>Défénitions</a>
                <a href="sites.php" target="_self"><img src="img/menu/dot-g.png"/>Sites recommandés</a>
                <a href="livres.php" target="_self"><img src="img/menu/dot-g.png"/>Livres recommandés</a>
                <a href="ressources.php" target="_self"><img src="img/menu/dot-g.png"/>Ressources</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <a href="recherche.php" title="Rechercher sur le site" target="_self"><img class="sans-texte" src="img/menu/recherche.png"/></a>
        <a href="a-propos.php" title="À propos" target="_self"><img class="sans-texte" src="img/menu/a-propos-g.png"/></a>
        <a href="contact.php" title="M'écrire" target="_self"><img class="sans-texte" src="img/menu/enveloppe-g.png"/></a>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/renedemoors" title="Me joindre sur Facobook" target="_blank"><img class="sans-texte" src="img/partage/facebook-s.png"/></a>
        <a href="   <?php 
            $url= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
            $positionslash= strrpos($url, "/ ");
            $filename= substr($url, $positionslash + 1);
            echo "en/ ". $filename;
            ?>  " title="english" target="_self"><span class="menu-lang">English</span>
        </a>

        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()"><img src="img/menu/bars-g.png" alt="menu"/></a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
            <div class="menu-open"><img src="img/menu/bars-g.png" alt="menu"/>
            </div>
            <div class="menu-close"><img src="img/menu/times-r.png" alt="fermer"/>
            </div>
        </a>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could provide a minimal example replicating the behavior. I think the wall of css and html are a bit off putting. Also try and tag the applicable technologies so that people who specialize in those disciplines  see your question.

Comment: Thanks, James Powis for your help. I don't see what example I could give. I just can't see all the menu links because they are out of screen. I did put the link of my Webiste for those who wants to check by themselves. For the css and html being a bit of putting : I'm not surprised as I don't know very much what I'm doing : I know very little about  css and I go whith trial an error. I'll put more tags. Thanks for the advice. :)

Comment: If we check the Website https://www.velir.com/blog , we notice that we can scroll the menu so we can see all the links, even when the mobile phone is on landscape position.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem solved :**

I added **height: 100vh;** and **overflow: auto;**

**So before if was like this:**

```
.topnav.responsive {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: black;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 204;
    letter-spacing: normal;     
}
```

**An now it is like this :**

```
.topnav.responsive {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: black;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 204;
    letter-spacing: normal;     
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: auto;
}
```